# Throw an exception when a user redefines a variable I already predefined in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, variables, exception, typeof

How do I throw an exception when a user tries to redefine a variable I already predefined in a framework as a class?

framework script

```
function Car(){
this.loc=new Location();
}  

function Location(x,y,z){
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.z=z;
}
```

example user script

```
mycar=new Car();
mycar.loc.x=100;
mycar.loc.y=10;
mycar.loc.z=100;
```

Is there a way to throw an error when a user accidentally does this:

```
mycar=new Car();
mycar.loc=5; //assigns a number to what is supposed to be a Location class.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Here's an (untested) example how it can look like:

```
function Car(){
   let loc = new Location();

   Object.defineProperty(this, "loc", {
       get: function() { return loc; },
       writable: false,
   });
}  

function Location(x,y,z){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.z=z;
}
```

**Update:**

To actually throw an error, you need to do

```
   Object.defineProperty(this, "loc", {
       get: function() { return loc; },
       set: function(value) {
         if (value instanceof Location) {
           loc = value
         } else {
           throw Error('Dont do this')
         }
       },
   });
```

Comment: Setting writable to `false` won't actually result in an error. You'd have to write a custom setter to do that.

Comment: This works. A user cannot set mycar.loc=5.  Is there any way to allow the user to set mycar.loc=a Location since it's the correct type.

Comment: Yes, I've added a validation now

Comment: Great! Thanks for a complete solution. Before the user could accidentally rewrite the framework and destroy it without any errors or feedback.  Now if the user makes an error they will get a nice error message.

Comment: I get "Don't do this" when trying this: loc=new Location(1,2,3);
mycar=new Car();
mycar.loc=loc;  Is there something I have to change about my Location definition?

Comment: You're sure you didn't get `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`? I now changed `const` to `let`, except from that your pasted code works

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It's working now. I tried mycar.loc=Location(1,2,3) without the "new" keyword but that didn't work so I found a post about eliminating the "new" keyword and added the following to the Location definition which seems to work:  if (!(this instanceof Location)){
        return new Location(x,y,z);
   }  Thanks again!

Comment: Everything works great except that when it throws an error the line number of the error message is the "throw Error" line. Is there any way to get the line number that called the set function?

Comment: After some research it looks like I can put the throw statement in a try catch structure:  try{throw Error("Don't do this");}catch(e){console.log(e.stack)}  The line number that called the set function is in the stack trace information. Each browser writes the stack information in a different way though so it has to be customized for each browser. So with this addition now it gives the correct line number for the error.

Comment: Unfortunately the line number is not available in some browsers e.stack. Is there any other way to get the line number that called the set function?